# Excel Addin -> Custom Pane with Html -> Dragging between 2 screens with different resolutions misplaces the pane content

Tags: c#, winforms, excel-addins, webview2

In my Excel Addin project (C#) I created a custom pane, which uses WinForms control, which hosts an html page using WebView2.

When I drag the Excel app between 2 different screens, with different resolutions the pane html content seems to go out of place:

[image: screenshot]

When I use a winform control without hosting an html page, this doesn't happen.

I tried hooking on the WebView2's OnResize, and also control's, and I see that size changes when content gets out of place, but don't know how to fix it. Tried various options like setting parent to null etc...

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a classic DpiAwareness problem, which is made worse since the Excel is a DpiAware process, which causes yours to become `SystemAware` if you didn't set it otherwise. -- Try to scale to `Dpi` instead of the default `Font` to see if it gets better. -- See also: [SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setthreaddpiawarenesscontext) (Thread-based DpiAwareness instead of per-process awareness)